# Why front-page.php doesn't show content of file instead shows loop

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

Firstly, I understand the template hierarchy a little bit and read all the answers given by experts but unfortunately didn't get that.

Here is the problem I face:

1. If I use `home.php` then the content of the file is used on the home-page but when I set the static page for blog posts then the content of `home.php` is showed on the page. (I know the template hierarchy).
2. If I use `front-page.php` then the content of `index.php` is used on the homepage and not the file content.

Now I am confused why the `home.php` works on the home page and `front-page.php` isn't shown.

Any idea why this isn't working.

Comment: What does “is set the static page for blog posts” mean?

Comment: sorry for typo error, it is "I" instead of "is"

Comment: That wasn’t my question. Do you mean you set the _front_ page as the latest posts?

Comment: No. I wanna use a custom-designed homepage, so I have to use front-page.php as a template? Right. If I use home.php then the content is shown inside the static page which I set as a blog posts page which lists posts. But if use file name front-page.php instead of home.php nothing is shown in the homepage just the loop of index.php

Comment: I wanna know why front-page.php isn't working for the homepage but home.php works